# golang exec with cmd as argument does not print stdout

Tags: go, exec, stdout

```
cmdstr := "ssh -i ....... blah blah blah" ssh to an ip and run rpm command to install rpm
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", cmdstr)
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(out.String())
}
```

out.String() does not print anything
if I have ping command without /bin/bash it prints the out. Anyone knows why ?

Comment: What is the error returned from cmd.Run? What is the output when err is nil?

Answer (score 0):

cmd.Stdout captures the output of a successful command execution

cmd.Stderr captures the command output if an error occurs during execution

You could try the cmd.Output() variant and capture execution errors from Stderr using

```golang
cmdstr := "ssh -i ....... blah blah blah" // ssh to an ip and run rpm command to install rpm
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", cmdstr)
var errb bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stderr = &errb
output, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %s", errb.String()) // capture any error output
}

fmt.Println(string(output)) // when successful
```